# Derivative of $G(r,\phi)=f(r\cos(\phi),r\sin(\phi))$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $(x,y)=(r\cos(\phi),r\sin(\phi))$, $r>0$ and $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ a $C^2-$function and $G(r,\phi)=f(r\cos(\phi),r\sin(\phi))$. I want to know how to calculate the derivatives $\frac{\partial G(r,\phi)}{\partial r}$, $\frac{\partial G(r,\phi)}{\partial \phi}$ and $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}$.

For example, I tried to calculate this $\frac{\partial G(r,\phi)}{\partial r}$ derivation with the chain rule: $\frac{\partial G(r,\phi)}{\partial r}=f_r'(r\cos(\phi),r\sin(\phi))\cdot (\cos(\phi),\sin(\phi))$, but I think it isn't correct. Could you help me? Regards.

Answer (score 0):

By chain rule
$$\frac{\partial G(r,\phi)}{\partial r}=f_x\cdot \cos\phi+f_y\cdot\sin\phi$$

Answer (score 0):

We have

$$G(r,\phi)=f(r\cos \phi, r\sin \phi)$$

Using the chain rule, we have

$$\frac{\partial G}{\partial r}=f_1(r\cos \phi, r\sin \phi)\cos \phi+f_2(r\cos \phi, r\sin \phi)\sin \phi$$

and

$$\frac{\partial G}{\partial \phi}=-f_1(r\cos \phi, r\sin \phi)r\sin \phi+f_2(r\cos \phi, r\sin \phi)r\cos \phi$$

where $f_1$ and $f_2$ designate partial derivatives of $f$ with respect to the first and second arguments, respectively.